# Trying to update TextView using Number Picker

Tags: android, textview, settext, numberpicker

I am trying to update the value displayed in a TextView when the user changes the value inside the number picker widget.

I have the number picker set up and working correctly however when I attempt to call the TextView's .setText() method I get the following error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.waitron5.MenuItemArrayAdapter.onValueChange(MenuItemArrayAdapter.java:68)**

Below is the code corresponding to where the error seems to be occuring in the MenuItemArrayAdapter class:

```
@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Change: " + picker.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //if oldVal > newVal increment price
    price.setText("xyz");
    //if oldVal < newVal decrement price
}
```

The Toast message was put in to test the listener was working correctly and it was. I then added the setText() method but that caused the error.

Any help on the issue would be much appreciated! I declare the TextView at the top of the MenuItemArrayAdapter class:

```
private TextView price;
```

NOTE: The number picker is contained within each view of a list. Which is why I have the MenuItemAdapter class. Could the problem be linked to trying to update the textView from the wrong location?

Below is the getView() method of the MenuItemAdapter class.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menuitem_row, null);
    }

    //assign values to view
    MenuItem item = this.menuItems.get(position);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView priceView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

    nameView.setText(item.getName() + " ");
    priceView.setText("€"+ String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);

    //number picker
    np = (NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.numpick);
    np.setMaxValue(99);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setValue(0);

    np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Do you ever assign a value to `price`?

Comment: By default I have price assigned a value "€0.00" which I did from within the XML layout file using android:text="".

Comment: have you initialize `price` textview after `setContentView`  ?

Comment: Yes within the getView() method I do the following: price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);. I can post the code to this method if it helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the TextView `price` available in each row of the `ListView`?
I suppose the answer is no, like you just have a single TextView on the screen that should display the total price.

If my assumption is right, then you sould not instantiate the `price` in the `getView()`

```
price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);
```

as the `price` will be searched in the `R.layout.menuitem_row` layout. If the TextView is not there, NullPointer will be thrown when you'll attempt to use.

The solution would be to instantiate the `price` in the onCreate() where your main layout is declared, and then pass it as a parameter to the `MenuItemArrayAdapter`.

Something like this:

```
// ....
TextView price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price);
adapter = new MenuItemArrayAdapter(this, price); 
this.setAdapter(adapter)
//....
```

Then modify the constructor of `MenuItemArrayAdapter` to accept a TextView:

```
public MenuItemArrayAdapter(Context context, TextView price){
  this.context = context;
  this.price=price
}
```

After that you can use safely `price` to update it.

Comment: I'll try that now, I have a good feeling about your suggestion, it makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Thanks, once again you helped me out big time!